# PowerQuery: How to remove the whole row If value in a certain cell is empty or null

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

How can I remove a full row if certain cell in that row is null.

[image]

I would like to remove row 3 and 5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the drop down arrow filter atop the column to uncheck null  (or blank)

[image]

you can also chain them

= Table.SelectRows(#"PriorStepNameHere", each [Column1] <> null and  [Column2] <> null)